# Render json from multipart request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, multipartform-data, multipart

I would like to return a json response from my API after a multipart request.

The request is successful and saves everything as I would expect, but I can't seem to render json afterwards - it just renders html.

Here is my code:

```
 def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        format.multipart_form { render :show, status: :created, location: @article }
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @article }
      else
        format.multipart_form { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I'm sending the request from an iOS application and here are the request headers:

```
{
    "Content-Length" = 563285;
    "Content-Type" = "multipart/form-data; boundary=2EA4A96C-18A6-4E1E-9140-DAC63D1066E7";
}
```

Do I need to specify something else in my request or is there something that I'm doing wrong inside my rails `create` method?

Answer (score 2):

why do you 'render :show' on a successful save? wouldn't you want to

this line looks wrong:

```
format.multipart_form { render :show, status: :created, location: @article }
```

would this be more suitable?

```
format.multipart_form { render :json => @article, status: :created }
```

Comment: I was hoping to render my show.json.jbuilder. This works, which is awesome, but it would be amazing if it could render my jbuilder content, instead of @article.to_json

Comment: I don't see a way to explicity use a jBuilder template from a different format. It must exist. I prefer active-model-serializer personally.

Comment: I'll take a look at that. jBuilder is very restricting, although easy to use.

Comment: Cool. I find AMS to be really simple and as powerful as needed. If you give it a try let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to mention that the format you want to render is `json`. then you can use `jbuilder` as usual

so it should be

```rb
render :show, formats: :json, status: :created, location: @article
```